# Magento Get Product Attribute Text in Stock.php

Tags: php, magento, stock, magento-1.8, m2e-pro

I've been trying to adjust the amount stock reduced by a sale, depending on a product's attribute, I've tried the following methods, but seem to be getting nowhere.

Magento Version: 1.8.0.0

File: /app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/Model/Resource/Stock.php

Around line 158 after: foreach ($productQtys as $productId => $qty)

I have added the following code:

```
$CheckLength = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item['product_id'])->getData('length');
if ( $CheckLength == 'Per Half Metre' )
{
    $qty = $qty / 2;
}
```

and also tried this:

```
$myproduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');

if ($myproduct->getAttributeText('length')=='per Half Metre')
{
    $qty = $qty / 2;
}
```

and this:

```
$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId(); // return current store id
$CheckLength = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')->getAttributeRawValue($productId, 'length', $storeId);

if ( $CheckLength == 'Per Half Metre' )
{
    $qty = $qty / 2;
}
```

None of the above seem to work. Without the check, the qty divides by 2 quite nicely as I need, but I only need it to do it if the Product Attribute is "Per Half Metre".

PS: This attribute is in a drop down with 2 other options.

Hope someone can help! Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally figured it out, the following works - I must have tried 15 different variations before this worked.

```
$myproduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
$mylength = $myproduct->getAttributeText('length');
```

Thanks to BuzzJoe for pointing me in the right direction, I eventually used:

```
Mage::Log('$productId: '.$productId, null, 'mylogfile.log');
Mage::Log('$mylength: '.$mylength, null, 'mylogfile.log');
```

to keep a check on things. Couldn't get var_dump to work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to var_dump($CheckLength)? Maybe the value does not appear in the way you think.

And, by the way: It is never a good idea to edit core files. You should develop an extension instead.

Comment: Thanks BuzzJoe. I wondered how to get a value to display, so's I could check it, will this dump to a log or screen at the time of processing?

Comment: sort of. var_dump() will prompt the variable's value and it's type in the script's output. So, it will appear when you reload a page in your browser where this line of code will run. You can write it to magento's log file, too. Just search for how to do that.